# Swift code, no webview on app

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I'm new to xcode and swift

Im using this code to create a webview app just for myself, the app loads up with the starter screen, but then its blank white, the website does not load. What am i missing ?

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView!


    var webview: WKWebView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let url = NSURL (string: "http://www.gunchester.com");
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
        myWebView.loadRequest(requestObj);
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Comment: In iOS 9, you can't load an `http` URL by default.

Comment: You have both a UIWebView and a WKWebView?

Comment: ive removed wkwebview.

Comment: how would i go about loading the url ?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=site:stackoverflow.com+ios+9+load+http&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: I know about HTTPS and Transport Security in iOS 9 but does that also apply to web views? If so then how come the ops url will load in mobile Safari?